# readxl, selected worksheets in single .xlsx-workbook

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

How do I succinctly import selected sheets, preferably using [readxl](/questions/tagged/readxl), from a .xlsx-workbook?

With the below code (approach # 1) I can import all sheets in a single .xlsx-workbook, but how do I `filter()` or `select()` ? The second bit of code, with the `map_dfr()`, approach # 2, is kinda more succinct, but using that approach the `sheet` vector looses it's names and becomes a 1, 2, ctc.

Say I only want to import the sheets `iris` and `mtcars`

```
sh_to_impt <- c('iris', 'mtcars')
```

packages needed,

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
```

#### code approach # 1,

```
path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
datasets_data <- readxl::excel_sheets(path = path) %>% 
  purrr::set_names() %>% select(mtcars) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    ~ readxl::read_excel(path = path, sheet = .x)
    , .id = "sheet"
  )

datasets_data 
# A tibble: 1,253 x 24
   sheet Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
   <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
 1 iris           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2 iris           4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3 iris           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4 iris           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5 iris           5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6 iris           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7 iris           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8 iris           5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9 iris           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10 iris           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 1,243 more rows, and 18 more variables: mpg <dbl>,
#   cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>,
#   qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>,
#   weight <dbl>, feed <chr>, lat <dbl>, long <dbl>, depth <dbl>,
#   mag <dbl>, stations <dbl>
```

I can get around it like this, BUT then the `sheet` vector looses it's names and becomes a 1, 2, ctc.

#### code approach # 2,

```
map_dfr(sh_to_impt, ~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x), .id = "sheet")
# A tibble: 182 x 17
sheet Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
<chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
  1 1              5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
2 1              4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
3 1              4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
4 1              4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
5 1              5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
6 1              5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
7 1              4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
8 1              5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
9 1              4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10 1              4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 172 more rows, and 11 more variables: mpg <dbl>,
#   cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>,
#   qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311769/1305688), thinking it might hold the key.

I’m looking for a succinct solution. A, to me, obvious not so succinct solution could be,

```
map_dfr(sh_to_impt, ~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x), .id = "sheet") %>% 
  mutate(sheet = recode(sheet, `1` = sh_to_impt[1], `2` = sh_to_impt[2]))
# A tibble: 182 x 17
sheet Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   mpg
<chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
  1 iris           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
2 iris           4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
3 iris           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     NA
4 iris           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA
5 iris           5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
6 iris           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     NA
7 iris           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     NA
8 iris           5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA
9 iris           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
10 iris           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     NA
# ... with 172 more rows, and 10 more variables: cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>,
#   hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>,
#   gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I worked out. Please flee free to improve or
criticizs,

```
    sh_to_impt <- c('iris', 'mtcars')
    path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
    
    path %>%
      excel_sheets() %>%
      set_names() %>% .[sh_to_impt] %>%
      map_df(read_excel,
             path = path,
             .id = "sheet") 
    
    # A tibble: 182 x 17
    sheet Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   mpg
    <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
      1 iris           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
    2 iris           4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
    3 iris           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     NA
    4 iris           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA
    5 iris           5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
    6 iris           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     NA
    7 iris           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     NA
    8 iris           5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA
    9 iris           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA
    10 iris           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     NA
    # ... with 172 more rows, and 10 more variables: cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>,
    #   hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>,
    #   gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

Answer (score 2):

A "tidy" way to represent an Excel workbook in R is as a nested data frame, e.g.:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2                                                                                        
  sheet  data              
  <chr>  <list>            
1 iris   <tibble [150 × 5]>
2 mtcars <tibble [32 × 11]>
```

So I would simplify your first approach by storing the sheet name in a column, reading the data as an additional column, and then unnesting it:

```r
library("readxl")
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")
library("tidyr")

path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
sh_to_impt <- c("iris", "mtcars")

tibble(sheet = sh_to_impt) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(sheet, ~read_xlsx(path, .))) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 182 x 17
#>    sheet Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   mpg   cyl
#>    <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 iris           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  2 iris           4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  3 iris           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  4 iris           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  5 iris           5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  6 iris           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     NA    NA
#>  7 iris           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     NA    NA
#>  8 iris           5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  9 iris           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#> 10 iris           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     NA    NA
#> # … with 172 more rows, and 9 more variables: disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>,
#> #   wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

If you didn't know the sheets you wanted beforehand, or wanted different subsets for different analyses, you could also import all of them and filter before unnesting:

```r
tibble(sheet = excel_sheets(path)) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(sheet, ~read_xlsx(path, .))) %>% 
  filter(sheet %in% sh_to_impt) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 182 x 17
#>    sheet Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   mpg   cyl
#>    <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 iris           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  2 iris           4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  3 iris           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  4 iris           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  5 iris           5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  6 iris           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     NA    NA
#>  7 iris           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     NA    NA
#>  8 iris           5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#>  9 iris           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     NA    NA
#> 10 iris           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     NA    NA
#> # … with 172 more rows, and 9 more variables: disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>,
#> #   wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. It's key to my question that I only want to import a subset of the sheets, there's a brunch of sheets in my data that causes problems, slows my workflow etc.. I would my grateful if you could rewrite your answer to include `sh_to_impt`

Comment: To clarify, that's what the first approach does. I just didn't declare `sh_to_impt` as it's only used once. But I'll add that if it helps explain.

Comment: I believe you should do the filtering before reading in the data. Depending on the size of the data to be imported, it can save you up a lot of time.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny, thank you for pointing out that important point.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

excel_sheets(path) %>%
  str_subset(sh_to_impt) %>%
  map_df(
    ~read_excel(path = path, sheet = .x)
    )
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)